# what is the best strategy to create a collision with MD5 Hash algorithm

Tags: random, hash, md5

I'm using the following lines to create a hashed string

```
  String source = String.format(%s %s %s", salt, firstPart, secondPart);
  byte[] bytes = md5(source);
```

my question is how can i find a collision? meaning finding two different strings which create the same output? what would be the best strategy? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article on MD5 has a [section on security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) which includes collision and preimage vulnerabilities.

> MD5 uses the Merkle–Damgård construction, so if two prefixes with the same hash can be constructed, a common suffix can be added to both to make the collision more likely to be accepted as valid data by the application using it. Furthermore, current collision-finding techniques allow to specify an arbitrary prefix: an attacker can create two colliding files that both begin with the same content. All the attacker needs to generate two colliding files is a template file with a 128-byte block of data, aligned on a 64-byte boundary that can be changed freely by the collision-finding algorithm. An example MD5 collision, with the two messages differing in 6 bits, is:

```
// Examples snipped because they don't fit in the window and I can't highlight the
// the changes in the pre-formatted text like the article does. Check the link.
```

> Both produce the MD5 hash 79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4.[38] The difference between the two samples is the leading bit in each nibble has been flipped. For example, the 20th byte (offset 0x13) in the top sample, 0x87, is 10000111 in binary. The leading bit in the byte (also the leading bit in the first nibble) is flipped to make 00000111, which is 0x07 as shown in the lower sample.

If you just want to find any two inputs with the same MD5 and don't care what that hash is, the collision attack is for you.

If instead, you need to find an input that generates a particular output, you need a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack). The references the article includes for the full theoretical preimage attack with computational complexity of 2<sup>123.4</sup> complexity are:

- Yu Sasaki, Kazumaro Aoki (16 April 2009). "[Finding Preimages in Full MD5 Faster Than Exhaustive Search](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-01001-9_8)". Springer Berlin Heidelberg.
- Ming Mao and Shaohui Chen and Jin Xu (2009). "[Construction of the Initial Structure for Preimage Attack of MD5](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings-article/cis/2009/3931a442/12OmNqJq4q2)". International Conference on Computational Intelligence and Security (IEEE Computer Society) 1: 442–445. doi:10.1109/CIS.2009.214. ISBN 978-0-7695-3931-7.

Note that this complexity is only slightly less than the data complexity of storing every possible MD5 hash output (without storing the string that generates the given hash, which may be very long): 2<sup>128</sup> * 2<sup>7</sup> = 2<sup>135</sup> (this is ~10<sup>27</sup> *Tera*bytes, which is several orders of magnitude greater than the entire hard disk capacity of the entire world).

And of course, there is always the brute force approach. You can compute MD5 hashes for incremental inputs in a loop until you find an input that produces the given hash. This might take a very long time. If you store these values, you're essentially creating a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). But you mention a salt, which is the traditional means of defeating a rainbow table. But if you know the salt will remain fixed (as in, you're attacking a particular password in a database), then you can brute force it with this method.

Finally, you can always do a web search for a given MD5: Google will happily tell you that `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99` is the [MD5 for **password**](https://www.google.com/search?q=5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99), and will probably succeed for an MD5 of any common English word (or even an arbitrary input string below a certain length). If you have weak passwords and weak salts, you might get lucky with this approach.